# Custom allocator pointer offset from multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I'm wondering what is the best way to work around a pointer offset issues when using a custom allocator for C++. Let's consider an example:

```
struct A { int i; virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B { int j; virtual ~B() = default; };
struct C : A, B { int k; virtual ~C() = default; };

auto p1 = std::make_unique<C>();
std::unique_ptr<B> p2 = std::move(p1);
```

In this case `p2.get()` is different from `p1.get()`, due to the multiple inheritance offset applied. If both `unique_ptrs` use a custom deleter, which forwards the contained pointer to some custom allocator, the pointer to deallocate will be different than the pointer returned form the allocation, which is problematic.

To combat this, I've made a workaround deleter which basically calls a lambda which does the right cast:

```
template<class T>
class MemoryManagerDeleter
{
public:
    MemoryManagerDeleter(MemoryManagerPtr manager) noexcept
        : mMemoryManager{std::move(manager)}
        , mDeleteFunc{[=](auto pointer) {
            pointer->~T();
            mMemoryManager->deallocate(pointer);
        }}
    {
        assert(mMemoryManager);
    }

    template<class U>
    MemoryManagerDeleter(const MemoryManagerDeleter<U> &other) noexcept
        : mMemoryManager{other.mMemoryManager}
        , mDeleteFunc{[=](auto pointer) {
            const auto cast = static_cast<U *>(pointer);

            cast->~U();
            mMemoryManager->deallocate(cast);
        }}
    {
        assert(mMemoryManager);
    }

    MemoryManagerDeleter(const MemoryManagerDeleter &) = default;

    inline void operator()(T *pointer) const noexcept
    {
        if (pointer != nullptr)
            mDeleteFunc(pointer);
    }

    MemoryManagerDeleter &operator =(const MemoryManagerDeleter &) = default;

private:
    MemoryManagerPtr mMemoryManager;
    std::function<void (T *)> mDeleteFunc;

    template<class> friend class MemoryManagerDeleter;
};
```

There must be a better way to do this. It feels like an awful hack.

Comment: `pointer->~T();` looks extremely fishy (as any explicit destructor function call does)!

Comment: If you have working code to improve, maybe the better site for asking is [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, explicit destructor calling in context of an allocator is extremely OK. As for the question itself, I do not see a better solution. C++  virtuals are not very friendly to allocators.

Comment: Well, the code does have a bug inside with the copying of the deleter and the deletion function, but nevertheless, it does seems like a workaround for something which should be solvable is a more "pretty" way.